# Handle System.IO.PathTooLongException C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, exception, file-handling

I am getting System.IO.PathTooLong Exception in `File.copy(file1 , file2).` 
What are other ways to handle it except shortening the names of file.

Comment: Long filenames are enforced by the operating system. Nothing you can do except handle the exception gracefully and shortening it.

Comment: @br4d The problem here is: The file name length is appropriate, but fully qualified name is more than 260 character. Is there any workaround.